# Use tensorflow Dataset to extract slices based on array of known indices

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to gather a dataset for a CNN based on a time series. The model takes 1D tensor inputs of 588 values at a time and classifies the time series based on a prediction that a known event will occur soon after these data points.

Because the data set is large, I can't load all positive (event did occur) and negative (event did not occur) slices of the entire timeline at once, hence I've prepared lists of the following:

```
series = [ ... list of entire time series over several years ... ]
indices_and_labels = [ (idx1, label1), (idx2, label2), ... ]
```

Thus for each known label I can extract the relevant portion of the time series with:

```
for (idx, label) in indices_and_labels:
    features = series[idx:idx+588] # 588 is the window size
```

How can I use a Dataset to do this for me automatically without needing to pull everything into memory at once? I tried this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(indices_and_labels)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: (series[[x[0]:x[0]+588]], x[1]))
```

But of course this fails because in the mapping function `x` is a tensor, not a tuple, so I can't use it to slice the series in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. `Dataset.from_generator()` is what I was looking for.

```
def generate_examples():
    for (idx, y) in indices_and_labels:
        yield (series[idx:idx+588], y)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_examples,
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(588,), dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32),
    ),
)
```